# Floating point reciprocal approximation using softfloat library

Tags: floating-point

I am using the softfloat library (http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html) to implement a single precision division algorithm. 
I am trying to understand the reciprocal approximation function implemented
as part of the softfloat library. Please see below the code. Could anyone
explain how they came up with the LUT? It looks like a combination of LUT and NR approximations, but a detailed explanation would definitely help.

```c
/*
  Returns an approximation to the reciprocal of the number represented by `a',
  where `a' is interpreted as an unsigned fixed-point number with one integer
  bit and 31 fraction bits.  The `a' input must be "normalized", meaning that
  its most-significant bit (bit 31) must be 1.  Thus, if A is the value of
  the fixed-point interpretation of `a', then 1 <= A < 2.  The returned value
  is interpreted as a pure unsigned fraction, having no integer bits and 32
  fraction bits.  The approximation returned is never greater than the true
  reciprocal 1/A, and it differs from the true reciprocal by at most 2.006 ulp 
  (units in the last place).
*/

uint32_t softfloat_approxRecip32_1( uint32_t a )
{
    int index;
    uint16_t eps;
    static const uint16_t k0s[] = {
      0xFFC4, 0xF0BE, 0xE363, 0xD76F, 0xCCAD, 0xC2F0, 0xBA16, 0xB201,
      0xAA97, 0xA3C6, 0x9D7A, 0x97A6, 0x923C, 0x8D32, 0x887E, 0x8417
    };
    static const uint16_t k1s[] = {
      0xF0F1, 0xD62C, 0xBFA1, 0xAC77, 0x9C0A, 0x8DDB, 0x8185, 0x76BA,
      0x6D3B, 0x64D4, 0x5D5C, 0x56B1, 0x50B6, 0x4B55, 0x4679, 0x4211
    };

    uint16_t r0;
    uint32_t delta0;
    uint_fast32_t r;
    uint32_t sqrDelta0;

    index = a>>27 & 0xF;
    eps = (uint16_t) (a>>11);
    r0 = k0s[index] - ((k1s[index] * (uint_fast32_t) eps)>>20);
    delta0 = ~(uint_fast32_t) ((r0 * (uint_fast64_t) a)>>7);
    r = ((uint_fast32_t) r0<<16) + ((r0 * (uint_fast64_t) delta0)>>24);
    sqrDelta0 = ((uint_fast64_t) delta0 * delta0)>>32;
    r += ((uint32_t) r * (uint_fast64_t) sqrDelta0)>>48;
    return r;

}
```

Comment: What are the input and output specifications for `softfloat_approxRecip32_1()`? For an input of `0x40000000` I get an output of `0xab0f9c81` which doesn't make much sense to me in the context of a reciprocal computation (assuming either fixed-point or  floating-point computation). That said, the usage of the two tables seems to suggest that piecewise linear approximations are used.

Comment: Plugging in a bunch of values it seems like the input is an unsigned 1.31 fixed-point number, and the result is a 0.32 fixed-point number, that is, a purely fractional number. E.g. input of `0xc0000000` (= 3/2) leads to output of `0xaaaaaaaa` (= 2/3) My limited experiments suggest that the functions provides an *underestimate* of the true mathematical result, in that all results appear to be less than, or equal to, the mathematical result.

Comment: Have added comment on the code. Please see.

Comment: I am more interested on how they arrived at the LUT and internal scale factors.

Comment: Reverse engineering further, the `k0s` and `k1s` are slope and intersect of linear approximations, each stored in 0.16 fixed-point format, that is, purely fractional values. This gives `r0`. From `r0` it computes `r`with one NR iteration `r0 + r0 * (1 - r0 * a)`, with `delta0 = (1 - r0 * a)`. Not sure where the `sqrDelta0` comes in, it could be for the next term in a series expansion?

Comment: The linear approximations used are presumably minimax approximations over each of the 16 intervals used, but I don't want to spend more time reverse engineering to demonstrate that.

Comment: I checked the literature and the *k-th* order generalized Newton iteration for the reciprocal is `r := r + r * (1 - a * r) + r * (1 - a * r)**2 + .. + r * (1 - a * r)**k`, so the above code implements the first three terms of this: `delta=(1-a*r); r = r0 + r0 * delta + r0 * delta * delta`. One often has a fair amount of freedom in choosing the scale factors used for fixed-point computation, but typically one chooses them such that the number of bits retained in intermediate computations is maximized for best accuracy, or that the point falls on (half-)word) boundaries to save instructions.

Comment: The linear approximations don't seem to be minimax approximations. Looking at the first interval [1,17/16), the minimax approximation optimized for relative error is 0.999540652 - (a-1) * 0.940744143. In 0.16 fixed-point, those coefficients are `0xFFE2` and `F0D5`, while the table entries in the code are `0xFFC4` and `0xF0F1`. Using a minimax approximation optimized for absolute error likewise does not produce matching results. So it is not clear how *exactly* the table entries were constructed.

Comment: yes, its not clear how exactly the table entries were constructed though it works perfectly!

Comment: The linear approximations cannot be minimax approximations, because this would cause `delta0` to become negative for some argument, which causes the code to fail as it expects this quantity to be positive (meaning the inital approximation `r0` is always an *underestimation* of the function value 1/a). The `k1s` are simply the slopes computed from the function values 1/a at the ends of each interval. E.g. On [1,17/16) the slope is (1/1 - 16/17) / (1/16) = 0.94117647, which rounded up to the nearest 0.16 fixed-point number is `0xf0f1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial approximation `r0` is computed by piece-wise linear approximation, using sixteen intervals, from [1, 17/16) to [15/16, 2), selected by the four most significant fractional bits of the 1.31 fixed-point argument. The initial estimate is then refined using the generalized Newton iteration for the reciprocal r<sub>new</sub> = r<sub>old</sub> + r<sub>old</sub> * (1 - a * r<sub>old</sub>) + r<sub>old</sub> * (1 - a * r<sub>old</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + ... + r<sub>old</sub> * (1 - a * r<sub>old</sub>)<sup>k</sup> [see [paper by Liddicoat and Flynn](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.3646&rep=rep1&type=pdf)]. `delta0` is (1 - a * r<sub>0</sub>). The first three terms of the expansion are used: r = r<sub>0</sub> + r<sub>0</sub> * delta<sub>0</sub> + r<sub>0</sub> * delta<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>. This iteration has cubic convergence, tripling the number of correct bits in every iteration. In this implementation, worst case relative error in `r0` is about 9.44e-4, while the worst case relative error in the final result `r` is about 9.32e-10.

The scale factors in the fixed-point computation are chosen to maximize the accuracy of intermediate computations (by retaining as many bits as possible), and to have the fixed-point conveniently fall on a word boundary, as in the computation of `delta0` in which the 1 therefore can be omitted.

The code requires `delta0` to be a positive quantity, therefore `r0` must always be an underestimation of the mathematical result 1/a. The linear approximation for each interval therefore *cannot* be minimax approximations. Instead the slope between the function values 1/a of the endpoints of each interval is computed, and the absolute value of that scaled by 2<sup>16</sup> is stored in `k0s`, meaning the array elements are 0.16 fixed-point numbers. Starting at the function value for the midpoint of each interval, the slope is then applied to find the intercept for the left endpoint of each interval. This value is likewise scaled by 2<sup>16</sup> and stored in `k1s` which therefore also holds 0.16 fixed-point numbers.

Based on my analysis, it seems that rounding towards 0 is employed in the floating-point to fixed-point conversion for entries in `k0s` while rounding towards positive infinity is employed in the floating-point to fixed-point conversion for entries in `k1s`. The following program implements the algorithm outlined above and produces table entries identical to those used in the code in the question.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("interval  k0    k1\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        double x0 = 1.0+i/16.0;       // left endpoint of interval
        double x1 = 1.0+(i+1)/16.0;   // right endpoint of interval
        double f0 = 1.0 / x0;
        double f1 = 1.0 / x1;
        double df = f0 - f1;
        double sl = df * 16.0;        // slope across interval
        double mp = (x0 + x1) / 2.0;  // midpoint of interval
        double fm = 1.0 / mp;
        double ic = fm + df / 2.0;    // intercept at start of interval

        printf ("%5d     %04x  %04x\n",
                i, (int)(ic * 65536.0 - 0.9999), (int)(sl * 65536.0 + 0.9999));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the above program should be as follows:

```
interval  k0    k1
    0     ffc4  f0f1
    1     f0be  d62c
    2     e363  bfa1
    3     d76f  ac77
    4     ccad  9c0a
    5     c2f0  8ddb
    6     ba16  8185
    7     b201  76ba
    8     aa97  6d3b
    9     a3c6  64d4
   10     9d7a  5d5c
   11     97a6  56b1
   12     923c  50b6
   13     8d32  4b55
   14     887e  4679
   15     8417  4211
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know how the required precision is achieved? The input is a 24 bit significand scaled to 32 bits. kth order approximation would give (k+1)x factor precision. Also, how is error in the result not more than 2.006 ulp (as shown in the comment)?

Comment: worst case relative error in r0 is about 9.44e-4, while the worst case relative error in the final result r is about 9.32e-10. Please explain. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Relative error is define as: (result - reference) / reference. When assessing the worst case error of an approximation one is interested only in the magnitude of the number, so compute abs ((result -reference) / reference) for all possible inputs in [`0x80000000`, `0xffffffff`] and determine the maximum of these values, giving the numbers in my answer. I used double-precision computation of the reciprocal as the reference: `1.0 / (a * exp2 (-31.0))`.

Comment: Please see below for scaling in the code above, it looks like the decimal points are not aligned. Could you check?

format: {bits before decimal point, bits after decimal point}

r0 = {1,15};

delta0 = {32};

(r0x(uint64_t)delta0)>>24 = {1,15}x{15,39}>>24 = {16,54}>>24 = {34,30};

r0<<16 + r0x(uint64_t)delta0 = {1,31} + {34,30} // decimal point not aligned??

Comment: Please check again. `r0` does not use 1.15 representation, but 0.16 representation. The input `a` is in [1,2) so the reciprocal `r0` must be in (0.5,1] but the approximation always underestimates meaning it is strictly less than 1. Therefore `r0` is a purely fractional number.

Comment: thanks. Please see a follow up question on reciprocal sqrt.